# While installing " GridDB Python Client " . Unable to set PYTHON_RESOURCE

Tags: griddb

I am trying to install "GridDB Python Client" on the windows system following the steps mention at https://griddb.org/python_client/cmake_build_guide.html

Step 1.3.2 mentions setting the path for PYTHON_RESOURCE in the CmakeList.txt file.

But the question is where to add this line ---> set(PYTHON_RESOURCE C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36) in CmakeList.txt file.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to just do like below
set (CMAKE_FIND_APPBUNDLE "NEVER")
set(PYTHON_RESOURCE "C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36")